# CSS background not working on my vps

Tags: css

The code works in local but when I put it on my vps it does nothing..

```css
.b-theme{
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, #99f1ff 0%,#c93cd1 50%,#9ee8fa 100%);
}
.n-theme{
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb83fa 0%,#e93cec 100%);
}
```

Comment: this is not reproducible. Can you use the console to check the CSS? Maybe there's some other code interfeering.

Comment: when i checked my other code is there but my background code is not O.o

Comment: then you haven't uploaded the code to your VPS.

Comment: i opened chrome in incognito and it appears now but in normal it wont appear